# refreshInterval = "-1" not working in spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using extended ElasticsearchRepository to access elasticsearch records.
This is the Document I'm using with repository.

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document(indexName = "index", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ESDocument {
...
```

However I see that POST traffic with refresh request is sent to server, but since POST is forbidden for my user I get HTTP error 403.
Is refreshInterval = "-1" option enough to disable refresh calls toward elastic search server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `refreshIntervall` in the `@Document` annotation defines the corresponding parameter in the index settings when an index is created by the Spring Data Elasticsearch repository.

If you get a 403 because you are not allowed to send POST request has nothing to do with the refresh intervall.  That a POST request is sent for a query is not something that Spring Data Elasticsearch is responsible for, that's the behaviour of the Elasticsearch `RestHighLevelClient` that is used.

If you cannot POST to prevent changes in Elasticsearch, your cluster should be configured properly for access roles (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/authorization.html).